# Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.3 - customize button does not work when I click on it

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-shell

I have just installed Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.03 and I saw that the customize button does not work when I click on it. Do you have any suggestions? I restarted it and still nothing.

[image: I attached an image of it]

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy gnome-control-center`?

Comment: This button should execite the program settings.  If you press the meta-key and type "settings", can you start the program?

Answer (score 0):

It seems GNOME Control Center is somehow not installed. You may try installing it by running the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

If it says it's already installed, you may try purging the package first and the reinstalling it.